Who would I contact to help fix this “siding?” Issue?
The siding, or I don’t really know what it is, appears to keep the elements out of the bottom of the house, (see the photos attached) is coming off the bottom of our house on the outside. Any idea what type of worker I would call for this? Siding company general contractor? Any help is greatly appreciated. ￼(the silver stuff coming down in the pics)



While I understand cladding the underside of the joists in the first picture, I have no context for what I am seeing in the second picture

I'm with @DelphicOracle...not much detail provided. Given that, I would just call a roofing and siding contractor.
